# repast simphony relogo tutorial Zombies; Has anyone come across the following warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, agent, modeling

I came across the following warnings while taking the step by step tutorial for Zombies on Relogo within Repast Simphony 2.0 Beta

The warnings are:

- Description   Path    Resource    Location    Type
  TrackingEdge is a raw type. References to generic type TrackingEdge should be parameterized  /Zombies/src/zombies/style  TrackingLinkStyle.java  line 31 Java Problem
- Description   Path    Resource    Location    Type
  BaseLink is a raw type. References to generic type BaseLink should be parameterized  /Zombies/src/zombies/style  LinkStyle.java  line 28 Java Problem
- Description   Path    Resource    Location    Type
  Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  /Zombies/src/zombies/style  TrackingLinkStyle.java  line 29 Java Problem

They do not interrupt the simulation but as I would be developing other models in the future I was wondering if any one knew what they meant, and if possible how to take care of them

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of the repast simphony mailing list feedback 
This is the answer to the question above

Hello Victoria,

Those are simply warnings and in no way affect your model.
If you're curious and would like to learn more about the first two sets of warnings, you can read up on Java Generics: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html
If you're curious about the last warning, try searching for Java Annotations online: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html

Best,
Jonathan